# I am trying to understand the line with string declaration

Tags: c++

```
string Possible::str(int width) const {
    string s(width, ' '); // <-- this line
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (is_on(i)) s[k++] = '0' + i;
    }
    return s;
}
```

What does that mean? string s(width, ' ');

Comment: fills the string with `width` copies of space.

Comment: Its one of the [`std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), for building a string of repeat characters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's an answer from my point of view!

Comment: Thanks guys! That link helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the (space) character will be repeated (width) times.

So for example if width is 5, the output of this line will be 5 spaces.

Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) example about using `std::string` constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Its one of the [`std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), for building a string of repeat characters.

Answer (score 1):

That line *declares* and *defines* object `s` of type `string` and specifies `(width, ' ')` as an *initializer* for that new object. This initializer will result in a corresponding `string`'s constructor with two parameters being invoked. That constructor will initialize object `s`.

If `string` is actually `std::string`, then this will invoke `string::string(size_t n, char c)` constructor. It will initialize `s` with a string of length `width` consisting entirely of space characters.